# Delegates and setting labels

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

So, my overall goal with this code is to set the text property of labels, from a different thread (in a safe manner).

```
namespace csDinger3
{
    public delegate void setlblStarted_txt(string text);

    public partial class ClientUI : Form
    {
        public void setlblStarted_txt(string text)
        {
            var setlblStarted a = new setlblStarted(setlblStarted_txt);
            if (this.lblStarted.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(a, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.lblStarted.Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
namespace csDinger3
{
    public class Program
    {
        // Some code that's not relevant
        public static void updateText(Int32 number)
        {
            setlblStarted x = new setlblStarted(ClientUI.setlblStarted_txt);
            x(number.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can understand (and please correct me if I'm wrong), I need to create a new instance of `setlblStarted_txt`, point that new instance at method `setlblStarted_txt`, but the issue is currently `ClientUI.setlblStarted_txt` isn't static, and wants an object reference.

I've tried using `ClientUI c = new ClientUI();`, but that doesn't work (because it's creating a new instance of the form?)

What am I doing wrong, and if possible, can you help me understand why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In .NET 4.0 you don't need to declare a delegate the most of the time.

Comment: Why are you putting this code in the `Program` class? It's the one that launches the app. You should be putting this in the code-behind of the WinForms class.

Comment: @Cameron I'm using this as the sort of central class but I guess I could change it rather easy

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 4.0, you can use actions:

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
     Invoke(new Action<string>(updateText), "some text");
}
else
{
     updateText("some text");
}
```

Also, `void updateText(string text)` does not need to be static.

Comment: @harismranb `updateText` is on a different thread, I need to call the method `setlblEarned_txt`.
Would I just replace `updateText` with `setlblEarned_txt`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to use `MethodInvoker` delegate to update your text. I suggest you to change this approach to simplify your code:

```
namespace csDinger3
{
    public class Program
    {
        static ClientUI aForm;

        static void Main()
        {
             aForm = new ClientUI();
             aForm.Show();
        }
        // Some code that's not relevant
        public static void updateText(Int32 number)
        {
            aForm.setlblStarted_txt(number.ToString());
        }

public partial class ClientUI : Form
{
    public void setlblStarted_txt(string text)
    {
        if (lblStarted.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                lblStarted.Text = text
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            lblStarted.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

You can achieve the same behaviour with using the `ThreadPool` or `SynchronizationContext` or `Dispatcher` (in WPF). Please see this tutorial for better understanding:

- [Beginners Guide to Threading in .NET: Part 5 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28485/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-of-n)
- [Understanding SynchronizationContext (Part I)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I)
- [It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)